# Getting lastModified date for item in Asset folder?

Tags: android, android-file, android-assets

My goal is very simple: I have a zip file in my assets folder and wish to get the last modified date of it.

I am able to access the file via the Assetmanager and create a file from it, but the modified date is the moment that file is written

```
    AssetManager manager;
    File checkFile = new File(source + "/" + "test.zip");

    try
    {
        InputStream stream = manager.open(fileToCheck);
        int size = stream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        stream.read(buffer);
        stream.close();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(checkFile);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioExc)
    {
        //stuff
    }

        long lastMod = checkFile.lastModified();

        Date lastMod = new Date(lastMod ); //This is returning the current time, 
                                           //NOT the modified date of the file
```

Can anyone think of a way I could access the actual last modified date of the file in the assets folder? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is you can include the last modified date into that zip file (e.g, lastmod.txt). You can then unzip and read that file.